# Exception has occurred. FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

```
 ~ master ● flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.3.0-24.1.pre, on macOS 12.0 21A5268h darwin-x64, locale en-RU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Part of the code

```
...
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await categories.doc('categories').get();
...
```

Cloud Firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Storage rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your security rules require that the user is signed in to Firebase Authentication before they can read and write data. The error message indicates that this condition is not being met.

The code you shared does nothing to show that a user is indeed signed in, so I'd recommend first adding some extra code to help troubleshoot this condition. For example:

```
assert(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null, "User must be signed in before they can read from Firestore");
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await categories.doc('categories').get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answear, mate. Yeah, the user doesn't signed in. BTW I was able to sign in before it's happened. pastebin.com/nZ6JDaqs. _AssertionError ('package:foodshare/services/categoryservice.dart': Failed assertion: line 21 pos 12: 'FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null': User must be signed in before they can read from Firestore)

Comment: Entire codebase: https://github.com/organicnz/foodshare

Comment: Your repository is private

Comment: Yeah, I've realised it quite instantly and It's been changed :)